# Zend framework - get config inside controller

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework3

I'm using this to build zend application. http://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication

I'm trying to get the config data I put inside the `config/autoload/global.php` and `config/local.php.dist` with the bottom line but it returns

> Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException

and also

> A plugin by the name "getServiceLocator" was not found in the plugin manager Zend\Mvc\Controller\PluginManager

Any idea how I can get the config?

```
$config = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('config');
```

Answer (score 5):

The Master branch of [ZendSkeletonApplication](http://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication) at the moment using Zend Framework 3. And `getServiceLocator()` in controller had been [remove in Zend Framework 3.](https://framework.zend.com/blog/2016-03-24-zf3-update.html)
So, if you wanna pass some variables from service to controller, you should create a factory. And pass the variables when instantiate the controller in factory.

**Example:**

Your controller name is `IndexController` from `Application` Module. And the factory class is `IndexControllerFactory`.

**Application\Controller\IndexControllerFactory**

```
<?php
namespace Application\Controller;

use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\FactoryInterface;
use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;

class IndexControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
    {
        $config = $container->get("Config");
        return new IndexController($config);
    }
}
```

**Application\Controller\IndexController**

```
<?php
namespace Application\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{
    private $config;

    public function __construct(array $config)
    {
        $this->config = $config;
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        // use $this->config here
    }
}
```

and here the configuration in `module.config.php`

```
'controllers' => [
        'factories' => [
            Controller\IndexController::class => Controller\IndexControllerFactory::class
        ],
    ],
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 5):

**This is for clarification**

In **ZF3**, if you are creating any classes that need in your application, make them serviceable, make them available in your application via **ServiceManager**. **ServiceManager** implements a container which stores registered services. So how is that? ZF uses a method called **factory** (in short, it creates object). It helps store services into container. We can then pull services from that container using **ServiceManager**. Let's see how?

**ServiceManager** is itself a service.

So using a **factory** let's make **ServiceManager** instance available in a controller (For example, IndexController). So that we can get any service using it.

**Application\Controller\IndexControllerFactory**

```
<?php
namespace Application\Controller;

// This is the container 
use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\FactoryInterface;

class IndexControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = NULL)
    {   
        $serviceManager = $container->get('ServiceManager');
        return new IndexController($serviceManager);
    }    
}
```

Let's register the ***IndexControllerFactory*** as a factory for ***IndexController*** so that we can use it. Make the following change in the **module.config.php**

```
'controllers' => [
    'factories' => [
        Controller\IndexController::class => Controller\IndexControllerFactory::class,
    ],
],
```

Once the **IndexController** is instantiated by **IndexControllerFactory** (by above configurations) the **ServiceManager** instance becomes available through IndexController's constructor.

```
<?php
namespace Application\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{
    protected $serviceManager;

    public function __construct(ServiceManager $serviceManager) 
    {
        // Here we set the service manager instance 
        $this->serviceManager = $serviceManager;
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        // Use this as you want
        $config = $this->serviceManager->get('config');

        return new ViewModel();
    }
```

What if we need something from **config** service inside another class instead of the **controller**? For example, we want to upload images into a specific destination. So how would we fix the upload path? See the following example.

We will upload images through **RenameUpload** filter. It has an option named **target** which specifies the destination of upload path. Let's create another **factory** for upload filter.

**Application\Controller\Form\Filter\UploadFilterFactory**

```
<?php
namespace Application\Form\Filter;

use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\FactoryInterface;
use Application\Form\Filter\UploadFilter;

class UploadFilterFactory implements FactoryInterface
{

    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = NULL)
    { 
        $config = $container->get('config');

        // Look! here we fix the upload path
        $uploadPath = $config['module_config']['upload_path'];

        // Here we're injecting that path
        return new UploadFilter($uploadPath);
    }
}
```

Do the same for the **UploadForm** if you need. This will be **UploadFormFactory**

Put the following two snippets in the **module.config.php**. This is for **UploadFilterFactory**.

```
'service_manager' => [
    'factories' => [
        // UploadForm::class => UploadFormFactory::class, 
        UploadFilter::class => UploadFilterFactory::class,
    ],

    // Make an alias so that we can use it where we need
    // it could be uploadAction() inside any controller
    // $inputForm = $this->serviceManager->get('UploadForm');
    // $inputFilter = $this->serviceManager->get('UploadFilter');
    // $uploadForm->setInputFilter($inputFilter), for example
    'aliases' => [
        // 'UploadForm' => UploadForm::class,
        'UploadFilter' => UploadFilter::class,
    ],
],
```

and this one for the **upload path** wherever you want to upload.

```
'module_config' => [
    // Set the path as you want
    'upload_path' => __DIR__ . '/../data/upload',
],
```

This is the **Application\Form\Filter\UploadFilter**.

```
<?php
namespace Application\Form\Filter;

use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;
use Zend\Filter\File\RenameUpload;

class UploadFilter extends InputFilter
{
    protected $uploadPath;

    public function __construct(string $uploadPath)
    { 
        // We're assigning here so that we can use it
        // on the filter section.
        $this->uploadPath = $uploadPath;

        $this->prepareFilters();
    }

    public function prepareFilters()
    { 
        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'image',
            'required' => true,
            'filters' => array(
                array(
                    'name' => RenameUpload::class,
                    'options' => array(
                        // Thus here we use it
                        'target' => $this->uploadPath,
                        'overwrite' => true,
                        'randomize' => true,
                        'use_upload_extension' => true,
                    ),        
                ),
            ),
            'validators' => array(),
        ));
    }
}
```

This is a one way of making things serviceable. So why is **ServiceManager**? This is for making scattered uses of objects stop. It removes **hidden dependencies**. This makes code clean and easier to understand. The principle is ***Good Design***.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do that you need to inject the config, as the getServiceLocator (and all other locators) have been removed from ZF3.

In your module configuration you have this:

```
'controllers' => [
    'factories' => [
        Controller\IndexController::class => InvokableFactory::class,
    ],
],
```

You can change the factory to create your own.

```
Controller\IndexController::class => Controller\IndexControllerFactory::class,
```

Here's the code:

```
final class IndexControllerFactory
{
    public function __invoke(Container $container) : IndexController
    {
        $config = $container->get('config');
        if (!isset($config['stuff']['stuff']) {
            throw new \Exception('Please add the stuff.stuff parameter in the config');
        }
        $myParam = $config['stuff']['stuff'];
        return new IndexController($myParam);
    }
}
```

`Container` is a PSR container.

In your controller add a constructor to receive the config you need:

```
public function __construct(string $param)
{
    $this->param = $param;
}
```

And here you have your config in your class, as an attribute.