# laminas: application wide access of variables from config files

Tags: php, zend-framework3, laminas

i'm on this for several hours.
i'm looking for a way to access easily application wide variables from config files.
i've read under https://discourse.laminas.dev/t/define-global-constant-for-use-site-wide/1455 that constants are not a good way.

on [Zend framework - get config inside controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43458606/zend-framework-get-config-inside-controller) its being said that i have to create a factory and pass the variables when instantiate the controller in the factory and from there i have to inject it to the view model or other classes.

but seriously this doesnt seem for me to be the best way. for example if i want to access a variable that i have stored in global.php or application.config.php i have to write 10-15 lines of code, create factorys etc. until i finally can access it ?

is there no more easy way ?

Comment: Can you make an example of an applicationwide variable?

Comment: for example I want to store the http path of an Amazon S3 http link in an variable and I need to access this Amazon S3 http link in controllers, classes and views...

Comment: I would follow Matthew example for the reasons he explained "makes testing easier, and tends to prevent errors due to failure to define the constants". Perhaps your variable can be a part of a configurable component that perhaps contains more than a single variable. But this depends by your context.

Comment: What do you mean by "part of a configurable component that perhaps contains more than a single variable" ? can you give an example ?

Comment: For example, let say your S3 link is a flag ( italianFlag.jpg ), and your app can manage 8 different: you have 8 S3 links. In this case you could create a "Flags" component where you inject an array of S3 links at constructor. You'll serve this component as a service: when you have a controller or, for example, a view helper that needs all available flags, you can inject this service using DI. It is just an example, usually this kind of data is stored is some DB table.

Comment: @SergioRinaudo sorry for the late reply. its not about the filenames for S3 - its about the container path (i.e. ilistings.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com)  

even if I would store this kind of data in a DB as you say, how can I make the Result of the DB Query applicationwide available ? same problem...

Querying the DB several times over and over to get the same value (the S3 container Path) doesn't sound a good way

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't necessarily take 10-15 lines of code, one line of code plus one line of configuration could be enough for this purpose.

In the Factory method that instanciate your Controller object a single line that can retrieve a configuration variable value could look like :

```
$my_config_value = $container->get('config')['my_config_variable_name'];
```

This variable must have been declared and initialized in a configuration somewhere, for example in a config/autoload/yourmodulename.php configuration file with a line inside the returned configuration array that look like this :

```
'my_config_variable_name' => 'mys3containerpath.com/xxx',
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to write custom factory. With LazyControllerAbstractFactory config will be passed to constructor parameter with type `array`

```php
// module.config.php
use Laminas\Mvc\Controller\LazyControllerAbstractFactory;
return [
// ...
'controllers' => [
        'abstract_factories' => [
            LazyControllerAbstractFactory::class,
        ],
    ],
];
```

```php
SomeController class extends AbstractActionController
{
  private $configParam,$model;
  public function __construct(ModelClass $model,array $config)
  {
    $this->model=$model;
    $this->configParam=$config['paramName'];
  }
  public function indexAction()
  {
    return ['param'=>$this->configParam];
  }
}
```

The same rule applies to ReflectionBasedAbstractFactory.